# How to convert a date to Julian Format in Java?

Tags: java, date, jodatime, julian-date

I've a stream of date values that arrive to me in a numeric format that I assume it's a Julian format (not sure about it). I need to compare those dates with my own date, so I need to convert "my" date to that numeric format.
I cant' do viceversa for performance issues.

Example.
My date si in "classic" format:

```
"Wed Jan 21 10:21:57 CET 2015"
```

I need to convert it to this numeric format (is it Julian?):

```
"1421832117"
```

How?
Pay attention: in the Julian date I need also time infos, not only date!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535983/convert-a-regular-date-to-julian-date-and-vice-versa-in-java) helps.

Comment: It doesn't look like a Julian date, I think it is the number of seconds since Unix epoch.

Comment: Indeed - which is easy to get at once you've got a `Date` object. Where does "my" date come from? Is it really as a string, or is that just the result of calling `toString()` on a `Date`?

Comment: Well you can use Joda time library if you need further help or snippet for it you may ask here

Answer (score 0):

You may pass Arg (Input) with your provided date format and the method below will parse it in Millis (your desired format)

```
private void parseDateTime(String input){
    DateTimeZone CET = DateTimeZone.forID("CET");
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'CET' yyyy").withZone(CET);
    DateTime parsed = dtf.parseDateTime(input);
    Log.d("Millis for classic","" + parsed.getMillis());
}
```

OUTPUT : 01-28 20:40:56.787: D/Millis for classic(22559): 1421832117000

Answer (score 0):

## Count of seconds since 1970

You have apparently mistaken a count of whole seconds since the epoch of first moment of 1970 UTC as a [Julian day number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day). While both counts, these are entirely beasts.

A Julian day number is a count of whole or fractional days since January 1, 4713 BC, [proleptic Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Julian_calendar) (November 24, 4714 BC, in the [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar)). The Julian day number for the date seen below, `2015-01-21` is `2457043`. Very different from the `1421832117` input seen in the Question.

## java.time

Using the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later, we can easily convert your count of seconds into a date-time object. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) to learn about java.time. Much of the java.time functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of up to nanoseconds.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

We can easily [convert your count of seconds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) since start of 1970 UTC into an `Instant` object.

```
long seconds = 1421832117L; // Count of whole seconds since start of 1970 UTC.
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond ( seconds );
```

You may want to view this by the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) of some time zone. Avoid using 3-4 letter abbreviations such as `CET` as these are not true time zones, not standardized, and are not even unique(!). A [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) is in the format of `continent/region`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneId );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "seconds:" + seconds + " | instant: " + instant + " | zdt: " + zdt );
```

> seconds:1421832117 | instant: 2015-01-21T09:21:57Z | zdt: 2015-01-21T10:21:57+01:00[Europe/Paris]