# how to convert from a calendar date to an ordinal date with out any modules

Tags: perl, calendar, julian-date

I need to search for a time range in a log file. The time stamps are in [JDE Julian date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171208/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-jdes-julian-date-format) and I cannot use modules.

The date format is `YYYYJJJHHMMSS` where `JJJ` is the days in Julian.

I need to convert the user input in JDE with out using a module.

Comment: That's not a Julian date format in the normal sense as far as I'm aware - normally "Julian date format" is just a day number, not a day within a specific year. Perhaps you mean a JDE Julian Date? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171208)

Comment: yes. you are correct.

Comment: Simbabque. no boss asked me to write a small script to the do that in perl and i have no experience in perl.

Comment: Why do you want us to copy a module here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that these number are date/time values makes no difference. They are integers (albeit rather large ones) and they can be compared in exactly the same way as any other integer.

```
while (<$your_input_filehandle>) {
  # I have no idea of the format of your input data, so I can't
  # begin to implement extract_timestamp()
  my $this_records_timestamp = extract_timestamp($_);

  if ($this_records_timestamp >= $min_timestamp and
      $this_records_timestamp <= $max_timestamp) {
    # timestamp is within the given range
  }
}
```

**Update:** To convert YYYYMMDD to YYYYJJ

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $in_format  = '%Y%m%d';
my $out_format = '%Y%j';

my $in_date = shift
  || die "Please pass date in format YYYYMMDD\n";

my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($in_date, $in_format);

say $date->strftime($out_format);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Dave Cross, i dont have a problem doing the comparison or search. i just need guidence or help converting from YYYYMMDD to YYYYJJJ.

example:
Input : 20150101
convert to : 2015001

Comment: thanks again, but i dont have access to any modules, just need to convert it doing simple math.

Comment: Time:: Piece is a core module. You'll have access to that.

Comment: @ManueldeOca "20150101 convert to : 2015001" That's not the J.D. Edwards Julian date format. JDE format for January 1, 2015 would be `1000 * (2015 - 1900) + 1`, or `115001`. Please edit your question to clarify, since you said in a comment that you were using JDE format.

Answer (score -1):

You should have access at least to core modules as `POSIX`:

```
perl -MPOSIX=mktime -pe'@F=/(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/;$j=sprintf"%03d",1+(localtime(mktime(@F[5,4,3,2],$F[1]-1,$F[0]-1900)))[7];s/.{4}\K.{4}/$j/;'
```

or with `Time::Piece`

```
perl -MTime::Piece -ne'print Time::Piece->strptime($_,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S\n")->strftime("%Y%j%H%M%S\n")'
```