# Conversion of calendar date to Julian date

Tags: xslt, julian-date

Please help me with the code of converting given calendar date to Julian date(YYYYMMM) 7 bytes format using xslt please...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: YYYYMMM is not "Julian date". I suspect you mean the JD Edwards date format, which is YYYYDDD where DDD is the day-of-year. If so, please clarify it your processor supports XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Referring to this date format as "Julian" seems to be very common, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171208/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-jdes-julian-date-format - but it has no connection with the Julian calendar (named after Julius Caesar) or with Julian day numbers and Julian periods introduced by Joseph Scaliger. It's a complete misnomer.

Comment: Hey thanks alot for your quick response....

Yeah true it's in YYYYDDD format... And my processor doesn't support any XSLt2.0 or date/time extensions ...

So only I am looking for logic on the conversion in xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **JD Edwards date format** (which is often referred to **incorrectly** as the *JDE Julian Date format*) is a `CYYDDD` format, where:

- `C` is a number denoting the century: a value of 0 represents years between 1900 and 1999, a value of 1 years from 2000 to 2099, and so on;
- `YY` denotes the year in the given century;
- `DDD` is the day number in the given year.

Thus, for example, the date of `2019-07-02` would be represented as `119183`.

To convert a date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format to JD Edwards date format using **XSLT 1.0,** you can use:

```
<xsl:template name="date-to-JDE">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>

    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="C" select="floor($year div 100) - 19"/>
    <xsl:variable name="YY" select="$year mod 100"/>

    <xsl:variable name="leap" select="not($year mod 4) and $year mod 100 or not($year mod 400)" />
    <xsl:variable name="elapsed-months" select="substring('000031059090120151181212243273304334', 3 * ($month - 1) + 1, 3)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="DDD" select="$elapsed-months + ($month > 2 and $leap) + $day"/> 

    <xsl:value-of select="$C * 100000 + $YY * 1000 + $DDD"/>            
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYj8

---

### Added:

If you actually need YYYYDDD, then you can simplify the above to:

```
<xsl:template name="date-to-YYYYDDD">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>

    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="leap" select="not($year mod 4) and $year mod 100 or not($year mod 400)" />
    <xsl:variable name="elapsed-months" select="substring('000031059090120151181212243273304334', 3 * ($month - 1) + 1, 3)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="DDD" select="$elapsed-months + ($month > 2 and $leap) + $day"/> 

    <xsl:value-of select="$year * 1000 + $DDD"/>            
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks again for your quick response. But I am looking for YYYYDDD - 7 bytes format.  For example , if given date is 1986-01-15 - need to convert to 1986015.Please guide us.

Comment: @Teja If you want YYYYDDD (where YYYY is the 4-digit year, and DDD is the day number in the given year), then just change the final `xsl:value-of` to `<xsl:value-of select="concat($year, $DDD)"/>`

Comment: @Tim.. Yeah used the same by modifying a little bit & generated. I need to calculate the day of the year..So I had taken that from the above code ..  Thanks alot! it worked...

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0, format-date() with picture `[Y0001][d001]` should give you what you want.

If you can't use XSLT 2.0, see whether your XSLT processor supports the date/time extensions defined at www.exslt.org